# React Native Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert class dev.thanhad.audioplayers.PlayerMode

Tags: react-native, kotlin, react-native-native-module

I'm creating native module for my project. I use `npx create-react-native-library`, type of library is `Native Module` and languages is `Kotlin & Objective-C`.

I add an `enum class`, add it to `getConstants()` and run example project it throw error below.

```js
Error: Exception in HostObject::get(propName:AudioPlayers): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert class dev.thanhad.audioplayers.PlayerMode
App@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=dev.thanhad.audioplayersexample&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:93290:30
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AppContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=dev.thanhad.audioplayersexample&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:84989:36
AudioPlayersExample(RootComponent)@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=dev.thanhad.audioplayersexample&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:89596:28
```

**AudioPlayersModule.kt**

```kotlin
package dev.thanhad.audioplayers

import com.facebook.react.bridge.*
import dev.thanhad.audioplayers.PlayerMode

class AudioPlayersModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) :
  ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {

  private val context = reactContext;

  override fun getName(): String {
    return NAME
  }

  override fun getConstants(): MutableMap<String, Any>? {
    val constants: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()

    // Player Mode
    constants["PLAYER_MODE_MEDIA"] = PlayerMode.MEDIA_PLAYER
    constants["PLAYER_MODE_LOW_LATENCY"] = PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY

    return constants
  }

  companion object {
    const val NAME = "AudioPlayers"
  }
}
```

**AudioPlayersPackage.kt**

```kotlin
package dev.thanhad.audioplayers

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager


class AudioPlayersPackage : ReactPackage {
  override fun createNativeModules(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<NativeModule> {
    return listOf(AudioPlayersModule(reactContext))
  }

  override fun createViewManagers(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<ViewManager<*, *>> {
    return emptyList()
  }
}
```

**PlayerMode.kt**

```kotlin
package dev.thanhad.audioplayers

enum class PlayerMode {
  MEDIA_PLAYER, LOW_LATENCY
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
  // Buildscript is evaluated before everything else so we can't use getExtOrDefault
  def kotlin_version = rootProject.ext.has("kotlinVersion") ? rootProject.ext.get("kotlinVersion") : project.properties["AudioPlayers_kotlinVersion"]

  repositories {
    google()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1"
    // noinspection DifferentKotlinGradleVersion
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
  return rootProject.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && rootProject.getProperty("newArchEnabled") == "true"
}

apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
  apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
}

def getExtOrDefault(name) {
  return rootProject.ext.has(name) ? rootProject.ext.get(name) : project.properties["AudioPlayers_" + name]
}

def getExtOrIntegerDefault(name) {
  return rootProject.ext.has(name) ? rootProject.ext.get(name) : (project.properties["AudioPlayers_" + name]).toInteger()
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("compileSdkVersion")

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("minSdkVersion")
    targetSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("targetSdkVersion")
    buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
    }
  }

  lintOptions {
    disable "GradleCompatible"
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

}

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  maven {
    // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
    url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
  }
  google()
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
}

def kotlin_version = getExtOrDefault("kotlinVersion")

dependencies {
  // For < 0.71, this will be from the local maven repo
  // For > 0.71, this will be replaced by `com.facebook.react:react-android:$version` by react gradle plugin
  //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
  react {
    jsRootDir = file("../src/")
    libraryName = "AudioPlayers"
    codegenJavaPackageName = "dev.thanhad.audioplayers"
  }
}
```

**example/android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**example/android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dev.thanhad.audioplayersexample"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()

        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
            // We configure the CMake build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments "-DPROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                        "-DNODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                }
            }
            if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
        def reactAndroidProjectDir = project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir
        def packageReactNdkDebugLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkDebugLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkDebugLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        def packageReactNdkReleaseLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkReleaseLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkReleaseLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            // If you wish to add a custom TurboModule or component locally,
            // you should uncomment this line.
            // preBuild.dependsOn("generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema")
            preDebugBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkDebugLibs)
            preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkReleaseLibs)

            // Due to a bug inside AGP, we have to explicitly set a dependency
            // between configureCMakeDebug* tasks and the preBuild tasks.
            // This can be removed once this is solved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207403732
            configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo.dependsOn(preReleaseBuild)
            configureCMakeDebug.dependsOn(preDebugBuild)
            reactNativeArchitectures().each { architecture ->
                tasks.findByName("configureCMakeDebug[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preDebugBuild")
                }
                tasks.findByName("configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preReleaseBuild")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") { // From node_modules
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
    // If new architecture is enabled, we let you build RN from source
    // Otherwise we fallback to a prebuilt .aar bundled in the NPM package.
    // This will be applied to all the imported transtitive dependency.
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building React Native from source")
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building Hermes from source")
        }
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
    // To opt-in for the New Architecture, you can either:
    // - Set `newArchEnabled` to true inside the `gradle.properties` file
    // - Invoke gradle with `-newArchEnabled=true`
    // - Set an environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_newArchEnabled=true`
    return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true"
}
```

Could you help me? Thanks.

I tried run `.\gradlew clean` and restart but not work

Answer (score 0):

When React Native says that it doesn't know how to "convert" `PlayerMode`, it most likely means that it can't serialize/deserialize it to bridge between Android and JS, as it doesn't know anything about your Enum. (Or really the JS side doesn't know anything about your Java enum, and obj-C enums are fundamentally different anyways.)  Whatever the case, it just can't handle a plain enum value as an exported constant value.  It does however know how to handle Strings.  So you can pass the name of your enum values through the constants:

```
    constants["PLAYER_MODE_MEDIA"] = PlayerMode.MEDIA_PLAYER.name()
    constants["PLAYER_MODE_LOW_LATENCY"] = PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY.name()
```

In the future when you start using React Native's "New Architecture" you can declare the available constant keys and their individual value types, and Codegen will make a whole bunch of type safe scaffolding for you on the Android/iOS side.  It's more work, but you can be assured that the two sides will align.